# Getting column from table as an array to using context_processor on webpage

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to pull column data from DB table using a Django context_processor. This table column contains different versions of the primary data. So need to collect all versions and pass it as context to the html page. The context processor function is as below.

I am able to get all the versions, but the format is weird. Any idea how to clean and only get the versions in an array? There are 2 versions currently Version1.9 and Version2.0 in the Column.

**context_processor.py**

```
def Version(request):
    value = ModelName.objects.values_list('version')

    if value:
        return { 'getVersion' : value }
    else:
        print("Unable to get Version")
        return { 'getVersion' : "" }
```

**Console Output:**

```
&lt;QuerySet [(&#39;Version1.9&#39;,), (&#39;Version2.0&#39;,), (&#39;Version1.9&#39;,), (&#39;Version2.0&#39;,)]&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a simple distinct list of different versions, you probably want flat=True, i.e.

```
value = ModelName.objects.values_list('version', flat=True)
```

That converts it from a queryset of multiple tuples to just an array of values.

Now, that doesn't de-duplicate it for you, but you can sort that out by converting it to a set.

```
versions = set( ModelName.objects.values_list('version', flat=True) )
value = ' '.join(versions)
```

Comment: Thanks Adam.. So I converted it to set. I still get the **'&#39'**. Why is this getting added?
 `{&#39;Version1.9&#39;, &#39;Version2.0&#39;}`..  
Do I need to remove that by converting to string?

Comment: Hmm, probably worth converting it to a string explicitly using join(). I'll update the example

Comment: Adam, tried your update solution. After the `' '.join(versions)` I get the output as `**Version2.0 Version1.9**`. 

I passed this as context to my Django Model and can access the variable on my HTML page. Over here I used JavaScript split - `value.split(" ");` to create the Array as `["Version2.0", "Version1.9"]` 

Thanks very much for the quick help!!!

Comment: Well, if this solved your problem you can click the tick next to the answer to mark it as the accepted, correct answer.